# GROUP BY vs DISTINCT with a constant value in SELECT inside a subquery - Performance Difference

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I noticed a performance difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT inside a subquery when a constant value is introduced `is_issued = 1` (if this is removed both queries works same).

The following query with `GROUP BY` takes 15+ mins
[Execution Plan - GROUP BY](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyfcVJrKt)

```
/*Takes 10+ mins*/
SELECT ld.[LNum],
       is_lease_insured = CAST(COALESCE(i.is_issued, 0) AS BIT)
FROM [dbo].[snapshot_ld] ld
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT LNum = value,
               i.snapshot_date,
               is_issued = 1
        FROM [dbo].[snapshot_ip] i
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(i.LNum, ',')
        GROUP BY value,
                 i.snapshot_date
    ) i
        ON ld.[LNum] = i.LNum
           AND ld.snapshot_date = i.snapshot_date
WHERE ld.RowIsDeleted = 0
      AND ld.bimonthly_snapshot_date_flag = 1;
```

And this one with the `DISTINCT` takes just 2 seconds
[Execution Plan - DISTINCT](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkBQ-JBKK)

```
/*Takes 2seconds*/
SELECT ld.LNum,
       is_lease_insured = CAST(COALESCE(i.is_issued, 0) AS BIT)
FROM [dbo].[snapshot_ld] ld
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               lno = value, /*Added DISTINCT and Removed GROUP BY*/
               i.snapshot_date,
               is_issued = 1
        FROM [dbo].[snapshot_ip] i
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(i.LNum, ',')
    --GROUP BY value, i.snapshot_date
    ) i
        ON ld.LNum = i.lno
           AND ld.snapshot_date = i.snapshot_date
WHERE ld.RowIsDeleted = 0
      AND ld.bimonthly_snapshot_date_flag = 1;
```

Should I use the one with DISTINCT and hope the performance issue doesn't strike in the future?
Or Can I know if there is there is a way to tune this scenario with GROUP BY.

Any help is much appreciated.

[Table and View Definitions](https://pastebin.com/6kLZnFZV)

Comment: Why use the constant at all? Just use `is_lease_insured = CAST(CASE WHEN i.LNum IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) `?  Also, what cause the need for deduplication? Duplicate rows in `snapshot_ip`? Duplicate values in `STRING_SPLIT(i.LNum, ',')`? A mixture of the two? Is `snapshot_ip.snapshot_date` unique?

Comment: `snapshot_ip.snapshot_date` is unique (it is just exploding the dates for snapshots). `i.LNum` contains comma separated LNums (loading from source as is). We have to join on the individual LNum's to say the policy is insured.

Comment: I can see that `i.LNum` contains Multiple values (which is a fundamental design flaw), what I asked is; if it contains Duplicate values. (In an attempt to understand where the source of duplication is.)

Comment: I don't see the point of using `GROUP BY` when what you need is a `DISTINCT`. If you are aggregating (summing, averaging etc) use `GROUP BY`, if you want unique rows use `DISTINCT`

Comment: @MatBailie, I see duplicates in the LNum field, the LNum's have been linked to multiple insurer_id's for some reason which goes beyond my scope. Thank you for the inputs.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I agree with you, DISTINCT should have been used at the first place by the developer. I was just verifying the performance issue proactively.